# How to allocate a folder or drive in my Windows PC for NAS storage?

Tags: windows, networking, nas

I have an IP Camera that has an option to videos to NAS destination.

I don't want to build a NAS box, as I have an existing PC w/c I use regularly and rarely turn off. So my question is, is there a way (or software that enables me) to use a folder or even a whole drive as NAS destination for the IP Camera?

PS
The IP Camera does not have an option to save to a SHARED FOLDER on the network, w/c would have made it a lot easier for me. It looks like i really need to setup a NAS destination for it.

An image of the IP camera share interface:

[image]

Comment: Could you put any detail as to what the camera is, what output/server connectivity it supports (FTP etc.)? If your webcam supports FTP then you could create a simple FTP server (SmallFTP) on Windows and configure it to store files on a partition/folder of your choice. You then point your camera at this server IP/port and it'll save your files...

Comment: Hi Big Chris, i believe the info you're asking for is irrelevant to my question. But to satisfy, it requires NAS destination in standard NFS or CIFS file systems (http://goo.gl/4H4DYp)

Comment: You should create a share on your Windows box (right click -> properties -> sharing) and then use the "SMB/CIFS" option on your camera page (as per your picture). If you create a user then you can secure the share and enter a username/password in the camera config page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On Your Windows Machine**

1. Create a folder - I wouldn't recommend using an entire partition because you have to use the format `Letter$` (e.g. `D$`) in your camera interface
2. Share the folder: Right click -> `Share with...` -> `Specific people...` -> add your Windows user (I would recommend creating a user specifically for this function - E.g. `CamUser`) -> grant the user `Read/Write` -> click `Share` to complete

**On your IP Camera Interface**

1. Enter the `Server IP address`
2. Under `Sharing Path of Captured Pictures` enter the folder name you created above
3. Under `Mounting Type` select `SMB/CIFS`
4. Enter the username and password of a valid Windows user (E.g. `CamUser` from above) on your computer that has permissions to write to the folder
5. Click `Yes` to confirm the NAS location

Comment: while this one didn't work for my camera (hikvision was a bit picky) I did learn that this is the way to do a NAS share using an existing windows installation, so thank you!